# CSS Sprite loading inconsistently on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-sprites

I have a CSS background sprite (2x size) that's showing up inconsistently on Chrome only. When I load the page, what is supposed to be a series of flags looks like this :

[image: CSS Sprite weird]

Now, if I use safari or firefox, it loads correctly

[image]

How do I fix this strange issue?

```html
 .flag {  
    background: url("flags_2x.png") no-repeat; 
    display:inline-block; 
    background-size:18px 7800px; 
    width:18px; 
    height:18px;
  }


.flag-abkhazia-12 {
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your current relevant code.

Comment: @Ihazkode added code